# Mock a network folder for testing in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Is there a way to mock a network drive for testing my powershell script on windows. I have files which need to be copied to for example

```
\\192.168.218.80\foo\2019\0815
```

but on my devel machine there is no such drive. Is there a way to mock/simulate this, so that i can test the copy process?

Comment: `\\127.0.0.1\c$\whatever\path` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the local administrative share using a UNC path:

```
\\localhost\C$\2019\0815
```

or

```
\\127.0.0.1\C$\2019\0815
```

Note that `C$` is the `C:`, `D$` would be `D:`, and so on for any locally-mounted letter drives. A directory mountpoint will still be available under the letter drive path where it's mounted to. Network-mounted letter drives however are NOT made available as administrative shares like this.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the Cmd days, `net use` and `subst` would be of use: map the UNC path as a network drive. When testing, use subst'ed local directory as the same network drive.

In Powershell, [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6) can be used for the same effect. For example, mapping an UNC path as `S` and doing the same for local directory works like so,

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential Contoso\ServiceAccount
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -Root "\\Server01\Scripts" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Credential $cred

New-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem -Name "S" -Root "c:\some\local\dir"
```